# NoMethodError (undefined method `User' for #<User:0x00000002586a68>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

When I add the validates before my case it works normal, but add the validates after give me a error

> Started POST "/users" for 106.37.100.61 at 2018-08-20 07:19:33 +0000
>   Cannot render console from 106.37.100.61! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
>      (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
>   Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UrrKnE8xR9phK4WEdyrgxgJSItgopSno2ZfyTHC1AIKG3WEs4iE17gDzp5xGzxXSrLG0cqOPP1cht7AvOSQMqQ==", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
>      (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>      (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `User' for #):
>
> app/controllers/users_controller.rb:31:in 'block in create'
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:30:in 'create'

This is my model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :microposts
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

My controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_user_micropost, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_user_micropost
      @microposts = @user.microposts
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
  end
end
```

Comment: It should be `validates :name, presence:true`
`validates :email, presence: true`. It should be symbol, you're missing `:` in the model before each of the attribute.
Also, please make sure, when you post your question, you format it properly, which makes it easier for all of us to read and help. Thank you.

Comment: You posted a lot of code. Please reduce your controller code to what is relevant to your question. I do not quite understand your problem. Which changes cause the error? Please add a comment to the relevant lines. A before and after would be helpful.

Comment: Do NOT add a link to the code image. Paste the code here.

Answer (score 1):

I know what happen for this

```
validates :name, presence: true 
validates :email, presence: true
```

I change the model in user.rb file

It works